# Wordpress archives in header -necessary?

Tags: archives, wp-blog-header.php

I just had a look at my source code and found that at the very beginning there's this really long list of archives. I haven't seen this on other blogs:

```
<link rel="pingback" href="http://zoomingjapan.com/xmlrpc.php" />
<link rel='archives' title='May 2015' href='http://zoomingjapan.com/2015/05/' />
<link rel='archives' title='April 2015' href='http://zoomingjapan.com/2015/04/' />
(.... lots more ...)
<link rel='archives' title='November 2011' href='http://zoomingjapan.com/2011/11/' />
```

It's probably the code in the second line in my header.php that's causing this:

```
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=link'); ?>
```

**My question is:**

What is the first line doing?

Can I remove both lines from my header?

If I remove it will it have any negative effects (e.g. Google crawling or SEO)?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this WordPress support page](https://en.support.wordpress.com/comments/pingbacks/) for an explanation of what the first line does.

The second line you can remove and it will get rid of those archive entries from the header output HTML.

For the SEO impact, search engines should be just fine as long as you have a site map for your posts.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks for the helpful link. So, I want to keep the pingbacks in there, but will remove the archives then.

Very quick, very helpful. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If you find yourself making many edits to your theme, learn about [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to help preserve your changes after theme updates that touch the same files.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I used a theme back then that is not updated anymore, but I'm just trying to update the theme files myself every now and then.